# Null pointer exception on <cfthread>

Tags: coldfusion, railo, cfml, application.cfc, fw1

The following code works on Adobe ColdFusion 9.01+ but not Railo 4.1

Furthermore, this only fails on `Post`

This code is called inside of FW/1 `setupRequest()` in `application.cfc`

```
<cfthread name="threadA" action="run"> 

<cftry>

<cfquery>
    INSERT
    INTO    dbo.Traffic (Circuit, Fuseaction, IP_hash)
    VALUES  (<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" value="#listfirst(variables.rc.fuseaction, '.')#">,
        <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" value="#listlast(variables.rc.fuseaction, '.')#">,
        <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" value="#cgi.remote_addr#">
        )
</cfquery>


<cfcatch />
</cftry>

</cfthread>
```

**Error**

> java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   railo.runtime.net.http.HttpUtil.cloneParameters(HttpUtil.java:66):66
>   at
>   railo.runtime.net.http.HttpServletRequestDummy.clone(HttpServletRequestDummy.java:677):677
>   at
>   railo.runtime.thread.ThreadUtil.cloneHttpServletRequest(ThreadUtil.java:67):67
>   at
>   railo.runtime.thread.ThreadUtil.clonePageContext(ThreadUtil.java:29):29
>   at
>   railo.runtime.thread.ChildThreadImpl.(ChildThreadImpl.java:101):101
>   at railo.runtime.tag.ThreadTag.register(ThreadTag.java:269):269 at
>   scorecard38.application_cfc$cf.udfCall(D:\railo\webapps\www\Scorecard38\Application.cfc:162):162
>   at railo.runtime.type.UDFImpl.implementation(UDFImpl.java:94):94

**Wild Guess**

`variables.rc` is not getting copied into the thread

Comment: If you want to test your theory, mail yourself a dump of the variables scope from that thread.

Comment: am I missing something, where is the start for cfcatch tag?

Comment: `<cfcatch />` is the same thing as `<cfcatch></cfcatch>` . Basically it captures the error and never shows or does anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`variables.rc` will not be copied into the thread unless you add it as an argument. Add `rc` as an argument and then instead of `variables.rc` you'll access it via `arguments.rc`

```
<cfthread name="threadA" action="run" rc="#variables.rc#">
  <cftry>

    <cfquery>
    INSERT INTO dbo.Traffic (Circuit, Fuseaction, IP_hash)
    VALUES  (<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" value="#listfirst(arguments.rc.fuseaction, '.')#">,
    <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" value="#listlast(arguments.rc.fuseaction, '.')#">,
    <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" value="#cgi.remote_addr#">
    )
    </cfquery>

    <cfcatch />
  </cftry>

</cfthread>
```

If that doesn't work you'll have to remove the `try`/`catch` and dump out your cfthread to see the error. The code below will output 'Variable C is undefined'

```
<cfthread name="threadA" action="run">
  <cfset b = c>
</cfthread>
<cfdump var="#cfthread#"><cfabort>
```

Comment: The variables scope from the main thread is accessible to other threads.  Are you sure you were not referring to the function?

Comment: I would assume he's already confirmed he can access `rc` in the function before he got this far.

Comment: I believe your answer to be incorrect.  The documentation on cfthread, http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-75a8.html, mentions nothing about passing arguments.  It does, however, state, "All threads in a page share a single Variables scope, so you can use it for data that is common across all threads. You must be careful to lock access to the variables, if necessary, to prevent deadlocks or race conditions between threads."  My own experience confirms this.  That's why I voted against this answer.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem s you. You are using CGI varaible and that's what is causing the problem